# 3D Mesh Vertex to 2D Pixel Coordinates

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, coordinates

I can obtain the coordinate of a mesh vertex with python via

```
wco = mesh.vertices[mesh_vert_idx].co
```

Further, it is possible to convert this coordinate system to the camera system with

```
cco = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(bpy.context.scene, bpy.data.objects['Camera'], wco)
```

But I am interested in the 2D position of the vertex in the image captured by the camera 'Camera'. In other words, is there a python method the projects the 3D point of the model to the 2D point in the image?